# Ограничить действие CSS, подключенного через cdn, только содержанием одного div?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, bootstrap

Подключил bootstrap через cdn:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Но нужно чтобы он работал только с содержанием одного div. Потому что портит верстку на остальной части страницы, а там другая библиотека стилей работает.

Можно ли cdn загрузить каким-то другим образом (через js или jQuery, например), чтобы он работал только с содержанием одного div?

Архитектура страницы следующая:

```
<html><body>
   <div id="A"> <!-- Здесь работает другая библиотека, которой bootstrap мешает -->
      <div id="B"> <!-- Здесь работает bootstrap, которому другая библиотека не мешает -->
      </div>
   </div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Подключать целую библиотеку ради одного div не рационально. Проще взять те стили который вам нужны и применить их к вашему div.

Comment: Тут не так, бутстрап действительно нужен

Comment: Кажется, ближе всего к тому, что вы описываете, концепция [Shadow DOM](https://learn.javascript.ru/shadow-dom). Но вряд ли это решение. Скорее, нужен просто дополнительный блок стилей, чтобы скорректировать поведение элементов.

Comment: Ну например попробуй вот это решение: https://github.com/toert/Isolated-Bootstrap

Comment: Или вот это если у вас есть препроцессор: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57219361/how-to-isolate-bootstrap-css-and-javascript-to-a-part-of-the-html-page

Comment: Спасибо, благодаря Вашим ссылкам вышел на нужное решение: https://github.com/onderakbulut/Isolated-Bootstrap-5/blob/main/bootstrap-5.0.1-iso.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Lukas, благодаря Вашим ссылкам вышел на нужное решение: https://github.com/onderakbulut/Isolated-Bootstrap-5/blob/main/bootstrap-5.0.1-iso.css

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста)

Comment: Всего каких-то 9000 строк :)

Comment: Так там уже все готово, бери и подключай )
Хотя списки де очень корректно в этой таблице стилей проработаны. Пришлось заново сделать. После первых 450 строк удалось все проработать стандартными "найти и заменить", минут 40 на все про все.